# Extending from JComponent for graphic objects?

Tags: java, jcomponent, graphic

I'm trying to make a Cisco Packet Tracer clone in Java for school, I made my graphic interface with clickable computers. To see if the mouse is on a computer, I'm using a MouseListener checking if the mouse is in the "hitbox" of a computer:
Every Computer extends from Machine

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
      for(Machine machine : networkManager.getMachines()) {
            if(machine.getBounds().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                machine.setHovered(true);
                isMachineHovered = true;
                machineHovered = machine;
            }
            else if(machine.isHovered()){
                isMachineHovered = false;
                machineHovered = null;
                machine.setHovered(false);
            }
      }
```

In my Machine class, I have this method (the collideBox is a Rectangle object corresponding to the size of a computer)

```
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return collideBox.getBounds();
}
```

I was wondering if it was better to make my Machine class extends from JComponent so I could use the MouseEntered method and all the other methods from the JComponent. Is it possible and is it a good idea?